# Microphone not working on HP pavilion x360

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, hp, microphone, pavucontrol

This is a problem I've scoured the internet for, but to no avail. I'm working with a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my HP Pavilion x360 Convertible 14-ba0xx.

The issue is that my microphone doesn't seem to work. The sound settings show only one microphone: 'Internal Microphone - Built-in Audio', which is turned on, and the input bar shows a full signal, meaning it is able to detect the signal. Also, all the settings on the alsamixer are kept at the maximum. However, when using Google meet on Firefox, nobody can hear me, despite my giving Firefox permission to use the very same microphone.

Also, while using Google Meet, there seems to be a weird feedback wherein it picks up incoming audio from the speaker and then sounds an echo.

Now, a post I read suggested the use of Pavucontrol: https://askubuntu.com/a/1227637/1116594

So here's the thing. After I followed the instructions in the attached link, I realized that Firefox only uses the 'Monitor of built-in analogue stereo', and pavucontrol doesn't let me change the option to the 'Built-in Analogue stereo', even though the latter option is available in the 'recording' tab of pavucontrol when I join a Google meet. Now, the result of this is that the other people can hear every sound my monitor makes (Youtube videos, system sounds etc), but cannot hear my voice. Also, I think the echo is a result of this very problem.

So, how do I get my microphone working for Google Meet?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Audio Input is set to your Audio Output. If you haven't saved your microphone permission settings on FireFox, go into Google Meets and make sure your audio input is on your microphone and not speakers. If you have saved your permission settings, go to FireFox Settings (open a new tab and click on the gear at the top right of the page), Privacy and Security, scroll down to Permissions, Microphone, and remove Google Meets from the permissions, and then try going onto Google Meets again and check what the microphone settings are on.