# sound recording does not work on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, microphone, audio-recording

the problem is that I cannot record using external mic in google meet and zoom and other programs
I tried installing PulseAudio and sound recorder and still the same problem.
inside sound recorder I set preferred format to anything other than mp3 it works but with high noise.
I have windows on the same machine and there is no problems with voice recording

EDIT: I tried an external usb sound card & everything still the same

Answer (score 0):

Install PulseAudio Volume control (pavucontrol). Then go to Input Devices tab to check if your external microphone is responsive there.

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

[image]

Then try solution in this thread. This might work.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1227637/1654625